# Cat a file with a directory including a variable doesn't work in a script - but works in shell

Tags: bash, shell, variables, logging, cat

When I set the variable `TS3LOG` to the first directory under `~/DockerData/ts3/` and then use that variable to cat a log from that dir which ends in `_1.log` ;

```
TS3LOG=$(ls -1t ~/DockerData/ts3/ | head -1) 
cat `/bin/ls -1td ~/DockerData/ts3/$TS3LOG/logs/*_1.log| /usr/bin/head -n1`
```

This is the error I get;

```
cat: '/home/docker/DockerData/ts3/ts3-jws3cffJBQwn5QIc/logs/*_1.log': No such file or directory
```

However once I exit the script and try to `cat` using the same command as the one the script failed with I get the following (and more info from the log that I won't bore you with)

```
docker@dockerbox:~/docker-ts3$ cat /home/docker/DockerData/ts3/ts3-
jws3cffJBQwn5QIc/logs/*_1.log
2017-05-10 18:17:10.363462|INFO    |VirtualServer |1  |listening on 
0.0.0.0:9987, :::9987
```

I've tried using `wait` to make sure that the files have been created before the script tries to cat them without any luck.

Anyone got a bright idea here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `ls -t` is a bad idea in general. See [BashFAQ #3](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) for the best-practices alternative, and [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for background on why.

Comment: Also, glob support can be turned off. It's important to make sure that hasn't been done earlier in your script.

Comment: `ls` can sometimes be made to force ansi escapes on pipes which would cause exactly this issue. `set -x` would make this immediately visible.

Answer (score 0):

The user that's running the script does not have the variable (for the directory) properly defined..  Try echo'ing that variable before you run the cat and you might get a hint of what's going wrong?

Comment: `echo` is often misleading -- there's no way to tell the difference between `echo "my file with spaces.txt"` and `echo "my" "file" "with" "spaces.txt"`; no way to distinguish the difference between `echo "spaces.txt"` and `echo "spaces.txt"$'\r'`, etc. Much better to log with `set -x`.